# Display cube when overlapped?

Tags: three.js

Hi all! 
I have a problem when run animation with three.j. See example: http://jsfiddle.net/5ywdE/13/
When the green cube is rotated to position of the blue cube, the red cube will be rotated.
Question: why is the blue cube displayed while the green blue is in front of it. I want the green cube is displayed in front of the blue cube (like so the red cube is displayed in front of all). Can I set the cube which will be displayed in front of other cube in case of overlapped?
What am I doing wrong??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

All the cubes have their `position.z` equals to zero. So... which cube must be draw first/last? Three.js doesn't know, just draw all of them, probably in the same order that they were added to the scene.

You can try to change the order in which cubes are added to the scene:

```
scene.add(obj1);
scene.add(obj);
scene.add(rot);
```

Or, if you are not going to move the camera, use a different z value for the blue cube:

```
...
cube1.position.z = -0.1;
...
```

Or you can just set to false the `visible` property of the blue cube when the green cube finish his animation:

```
...
run1= false;
three.cube1.visible = false;
...
```

If you can use `WebGLRenderer`, instead of `CanvasRenderer` as you are doing right now, you can use the `renderDepth` property to specify a "depth bias" for each cube.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I want to display all cubes. So, the solution 3 is infeasible. Solution 1 maybe OK but in case of many cubes, we don't know the order of cubes which run animation, moreover when two cubes are overlapped, Three seem to display one cube. I will try with solution 2. Thanks!

Comment: @Iptrung : I'm not sure what you mean. How can Three.JS possibly display both cubes if they are the same size and overlapping in exactly the same positions?

Comment: @Cory Gross: Sorry for reply late. I guess that. I see three.js only display cube which is added first. Using z value is good idea in this case.